# correctly tokenize english contractions with unicode apostrophes

Tags: python, spacy, spacy-3

How do you modify the default spacy (v3.0.5) tokenizer to correctly split english contractions if [unicode apostrophes](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Emgk25/ucs/quotes.html) (not `'`) are used.

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
apostrophes = ["'",'\u02B9', '\u02BB', '\u02BC', '\u02BD', '\u02C8', '\u02CA', '\u02CB', '\u0060', '\u00B4']
for apo in apostrophes:
    text = f"don{apo}t"
    print([t for t in nlp(text)])
>>> 
 [do, n't]
 [donʹt]
 [donʻt]
 [donʼt]
 [donʽt]
 [donˈt]
 [donˊt]
 [donˋt]
 [don`t]
 [don´t]
```

The desired output for all examples is `[do, n't]`

My best guess was to extend the default tokenizer_exceptions with all possible apostrophe variations. But this does not work as Tokenizer special cases are not allowed to modify text.

```
import spacy 
from spacy.util import compile_prefix_regex, compile_suffix_regex, compile_infix_regex

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

apostrophes = ['\u02B9', '\u02BB', '\u02BC', '\u02BD', '\u02C8', '\u02CA', '\u02CB', '\u0060', '\u00B4']
default_rules = nlp.Defaults.tokenizer_exceptions
extended_rules = default_rules.copy()
for key, val in default_rules.items():
    if "'" in key:
        for apo in apostrophes:
            extended_rules[key.replace("'", apo)] = val

rules = nlp.Defaults.tokenizer_exceptions
infix_re = compile_infix_regex(nlp.Defaults.infixes)
prefix_re = compile_prefix_regex(nlp.Defaults.prefixes)
suffix_re = compile_suffix_regex(nlp.Defaults.suffixes)

nlp.tokenizer =  spacy.tokenizer.Tokenizer(
        nlp.vocab,
        rules = extended_rules,
        prefix_search=prefix_re.search,
        suffix_search=suffix_re.search,
        infix_finditer=infix_re.finditer,
    )
            
apostrophes = ["'",'\u02B9', '\u02BB', '\u02BC', '\u02BD', '\u02C8', '\u02CA', '\u02CB', '\u0060', '\u00B4']
for apo in apostrophes:
    text = f"don{apo}t"
    print([t for t in nlp(text)])

>>> ValueError: [E997] Tokenizer special cases are not allowed to modify the text. This would map ':`(' to ':'(' given token attributes '[{65: ":'("}]'.
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need to add an exception without changing the text.

```
import spacy 

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

from spacy.attrs import ORTH, NORM
case = [{ORTH: "do"}, {ORTH: "n`t", NORM: "not"}]
tokenizer = nlp.tokenizer
tokenizer.add_special_case("don`t", case)

doc =  nlp("I don`t believe in bugs")

print(list(doc))
# => [I, do, n`t, believe, in, bugs]
```

If you want to change the text you should do it as a preprocessing step.

Comment: yes this works. But this apostrophe is not only existing in the word `don't` . It may appear anywhere, so i would need to write down all possible occurences of apostrophes anywhere. This seems quite a lot work with this method.

Comment: If you want something simpler, you could use a regex to replace the weird punctuation as a preprocessing step, something like `n[<weird-apostrophes>]t`. That wouldn't preserve the input but it seems like that probably isn't important?

Comment: yes, i implemented the functionality now as full-string preprocessing step replacing all apostrophes before using the tokenizer.
I had the wish to include this functionality in the tokenizer and not have a dedicated extra pre-processing step, but apparently this is the best way to solve it.